# ScraperWiki scrape frequence

Tags: javascript, scraper, scraperwiki

This might be a stupid question but I am currently working with scraping twitter by using Scraperwiki. Tho ScraperWiki run-frequency is rather low. Is there a way to force-run ScraperWiki to run more frequently without touching python since my knowledge is limited to javascript.

My code so far:

Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
var url ='https://free-ec2.scraperwiki.com/bjp3pty/5108654d5c234a4/sql/?q=select%20%0A%09created_at%2C%0A%20%20%20%20text%0Afrom%20tweets%0A--%20where%20created_at%20%3E%20%0Alimit%2010%0A'
$.getJSON(url, processTweets);


function processTweets(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        response = data[i].text; 
        response = response.toLowerCase();

        for (var station in stations) {
            if (response.indexOf(station) != -1) {
                showMarker(station);
            }
        }

    }
}
});

function showMarker(station) {
var pin = jQuery("<div>");
pin.addClass("pin");
pin.css("left", stations[station].x + "%");
pin.css("top", stations[station].y + "%");
pin.append("<img src='SLmappin.png'>")
pin.appendTo("#map");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your scrap in *preferences page*. To run every-(month, week, day).

But if you want to run more frequently (every hour) you have to upgrade your account.
I hope this answer helps you.